# .NET 6 Mock Program Class

Tags: integration-testing, .net-6.0

The problem is that if I use the code below, it still executing the Program.cs which in my case has custom middleware that I dont want executed in my tests. How do I go about to create a custom Program class, that DONT execute my main Program.cs:

````
public async Task HelloWorldTest()
{
    var application = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>()
        .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
        {
            // ... Configure test services
        });

    var _client = application.CreateClient();
    var response = await _client.GetAsync("localhost://home");
}```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.2
````

Answer (score -1):

Check out the documentation on integration tests and mock up your "custom middleware".

Documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0

I hope this helped you some on the way.